# BATCH - %Random% Loop

Tags: variables, batch-file, random, matrix

So let me start off with my code:

```
:Matrix
set /p matrixQ=Are you ready?(Y/N): 
if %matrixQ%==Y goto startingMatrix
goto restart
:startingMatrix
set /p loopAmount=How many echos do you want? We recomend 100: 
color 2
goto logic
:logic
set counter=0
if %loopAmount% LSS %counter% ( goto tricks )
color 0
pause
goto restart
:tricks
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
%counter%+=1
goto logic
```

So what I am trying to do is only print the `%random%` numbers a user-inputted amount of times. I tried with a `For` loop with no success. So, for some reason, all it does is set the color green and skip right back to the start with the label `:restart`. I have absolutely no clue as to why is doesn't go through the `if` statement to check if `%loopAmount%` is less than `%counter%`.

If you can help me out, thank you.

- Sa'id K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter will always be 0 because of where you set it in the script. You also have the counter and loopAmount variables flipped; you should be checking to see if counter is less than loopAmount. Also, you need to use the `set` command to increment counter properly.

```
:Matrix
set /p matrixQ=Are you ready?(Y/N): 
if %matrixQ%==Y goto startingMatrix
goto restart
:startingMatrix
set /p loopAmount=How many echos do you want? We recomend 100: 
set counter=0
color 2
goto logic
:logic
if %loopAmount% GTR %counter% ( goto tricks )
color 0
pause
goto restart
:tricks
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
set /a counter=%counter%+1
goto logic
```

Comment: Oh OK, thanks. I knew I had something wrong with both the if statement and the setting. I can't seem to find any pages that clearly explain what and when you should use each `set /[letter]`.

Again, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, ill check them out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your script:

1. Your counter and loopAmount are reversed in your compare
2. Arithmetic requries set /a
3. You didn't define restart
4. You reset the counter to 0

The below code works:

```
:restart
set /p matrixQ=Are you ready?(Y/N): 
if %matrixQ%==Y goto startingMatrix
goto restart
:startingMatrix
set /p loopAmount=How many echos do you want? We recomend 100: 
color 2
goto logic
:logic
set counter=0
:loop
if %counter% LSS %loopAmount% ( goto tricks )
color 0
pause
goto restart
:tricks
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
set/a counter=%counter% + 1
goto loop
```